# multiselect dropdown list with country flag

Tags: bootstrap-multiselect

I want multiselect dropdown list, country name followed by country flag.
and for now, I implemented multiselect dropdown using:

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

```
<h4>Employee should be from Country</h4>

<?php
    $html6= "";
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM jb_country";
    $runQuery = mysql_query($qry);
    $html6 .= "<select name='pref_emp_country[]' class='form-control' id='my-select' multiple='multiple'>";                             
    while ($sub_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($runQuery)) {
        $html6 .= "<option value=" .$sub_cat['id']. ">" .$sub_cat['name']. "</option>";
    } echo $html6 .= "</select>";                           
?>
```

this is my code using bootstrap-multiselect. 
multiselect countries are working fine. but now i want to add flags of each country before country name.
I want to know how can i do this!!

Thanks for time saving help

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is, and what code you already implemented.

Comment: Do you looking for something like this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Country-Selecter-with-Flags-flagstrap/

Comment: @djm yes, country flag and country name but with multiselect option.

Comment: @FarazAhmadJafri Now you can try to change code to fit your request: http://www.jqueryscript.net/download/jQuery-Plugin-For-Country-Selecter-with-Flags-flagstrap.zip
Perhaps, you know that bootstrap use jQuery library

Comment: @djm you are right but i want to implement it with multiselect option.

Comment: @FarazAhmadJafri Did you try to write any code? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: @djm now u can see what i want to do.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, I think now u guys can see what i want and tell me the solution if any...